# Can permissions and/or extended attributes lead to data loss?

Tags: filesystems, file-permissions, file-attributes, data-loss-prevention

This is related to having a portable drive in a format to be accessible for read and write in different operating systems. For example NTFS can be accessed in windows of course, in Linux quite easily and in macOS not so easily but possible. These three handle permissions and extended attributes in different manners. Is it possible that a file, a directory or several of them become inaccessible because of the permissions or the extended attributes?

Comment: What file system are we talking about exactly? To my knowledge only Windows respects the permissions of NTFS. FAT32 doesn’t have them. So [edit] your question to be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example NTFS can be accessed in windows of course, in Linux quite easily and in macOS not so easily but possible. These three handle permissions and extended attributes in different manners. Is it possible that a file, a directory or several of them become inaccessible because of the permissions or the extended attributes?

The only really significant issue would be the file encryption feature (EFS, not BitLocker) built into NTFS on Windows; you should be careful to not accidentally enable it for a file, as it would store the encryption key in *that specific computer* (among "Certificates"); a file marked as 'Encrypted' can only be accessed where the key has been imported (as a PFX file), and generally only on Windows.

As for the rest – while ordinary file permissions might cause difficulties, they will not cause data to outright disappear; at most you get a "Permission denied" failure, which can always be bypassed. As you note, it's the *operating system* that handles file permissions, not the disk itself, and you can usually ask the OS to bypass them. (Linux has root access, Windows has 'backup' and 'take ownership' operations, etc.) In fact, all of the Linux NTFS drivers *default* to ignoring NTFS ACLs completely.

The same goes for extended attributes. Most of them do not influence access and really just hold metadata; the ones which do (e.g. the specific attributes that hold Linux ACLs or SELinux context names) can be bypassed in the same way as permissions can.

It's the *lack of* extended attributes that might, in theory, lead to data loss, in case a program relies on them being preserved – which might be the case with some macOS software (see comments by Tetsujin), especially older apps that rely on "resource forks" or other HFS quirks; although NTFS is technically capable of storing any kind of metadata (including macOS forks, xattrs, or Linux permissions), macOS NTFS drivers might not bother storing or representing all of it correctly. (Programs on Windows or Linux practically never use xattrs for anything critical.)

Answer (score 1):

Writing Win, Mac or nix data to NTFS, HFS+, APFS or ExtFS will not be any risk to data safety, so long as you have the appropriate read/write software installed on each.
Permissions may be lost/affected/ignored, but the data itself is safe.

However, writing Mac or Win data to any FAT format can lead to data loss.
For Windows, this would be such as alternate data streams in multimedia files.
For Mac, it could result in total loss of data from such as Logic projects or Photos libraries.

FAT cannot use use symbolic links or hard links, as well as extended attributes, permissions & data streams. It's fine for flat files, no good for anything else.

Comment: Can you point to an example of people discussing about copying Logic projects, Photos libraries or Time Machine backups to FAT formatted drives? I have been looking for an example but have only found advise or instructions to use HFS+ or APFS. I would like to see what exactly gets lost when copying to FAT drives. I guess are extended attributes or metadata as you mention. But that may lead to data loss because, as far as I know, the new ntfs3 driver does not show nor copy them when the drive is mounted in linux.

Comment: You could try the Facebook Logic Pro group. I can't give you the link because Facebook kicked me off it for saying something should be screwed rather than nailed. That's "AI" for ya. Used to see one a day. "My projeks is borkened" The first question is always "Did you reformat the drive when you first got it?" because manufacturers insist on shipping drives MBR/ExFAT & Mac really wants GUID/HFS+ or APFS.

Comment: BTW, copying HFS+ Time Machine disks using anything other than Finder [which knows exactly how to handle them] is frankly comedic. Your 1TB drive is still happily copying when your 4TB you were attempting to move to is full & the copy still thinks there's another 16TB to go. Can't follow the hard links, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

The specifics depend on the filesystem, but if the files are only readable by a certain user/group, and someone other then that user/group (and usually but not always the administrator account) tries to read it - including backup software not run as that user - it will not back up the files.

I am fairly sure that the older FAT/VFAT filesystem does not have permissions baked into it, so it becomes an "all-or-nothing" backup proposal on that filesystem, sometimes making it a good choice.

Comment: User/group are only valid on the same system. No data loss will happen. Without external influence.

Comment: I think that you might have miss-read the question. Backup was not mentioned. Short, or long the answer is no.

Comment: You missed the portable portion of the question. At yor 63k ranking, I would flag this as a poor answer if I could.

Comment: I believe in the system, but not the reliance on historical answers bolstering poorly reasoned answers.

Comment: @agone don't misuse the "low quality" report, please. Wrong =/= low quality, if it was wrong. A wrong answer can be of very high quality. This attempts to answer the question, is formatted correctly and its content is related to the question.

Answer (score -2):

No,

Data loss via attributes is not a thing across computers.

Use Fat32 or ntfs, will not affect the readability of the data.

The addition of attributes upon mounting in OSX will add a ".resource/" directory, but there is no possibility(beyond normal wearing), of data loss.

I make no guarantees on writes, as that is a specific driver function.

But reading is universal.

Comment: Yeah, it is 'a thing'. Go on any Logic forum & see how many people manage to lose their projects after saving to FAT.

Comment: What is the relevance to this question?  One or more poor implementations elsewhere  has no relevance here.  I have used Fat32 since the 90's,  never encountering  a single problem.

Comment: I guess you don't use Macs much then. This isn't a 'poor implementation' it's FAT's inability to use symbolic links, hard links, as well as extended attributes, permissions & data streams. It's fine for flat files, no good for anything else.

Comment: That is true,  but a Mac will never attempt to store anything but the resource folder on a non-native formatted drive.   NTFS natively stores Mac file attributes. Hard references will never ever cross physical device boundaries.

Comment: *"Hard references will never ever cross physical device boundaries"* I guess you've never copied a Time Machine drive.

Comment: So my takeaway ifrom this  is macs screw up reading and writing of fat32 drives.

Comment: No. FAT drives screw up file data, because they are an incomplete storage medium.

Comment: Incomplete?  As compared to a better file system, when compared  to EFS4, Reiser, and XFS, I agree.  But as to OP question,  no data loss will occur.   Metadata loss for a Mac may be possible.

Comment: This is demonstrably incorrect.

Comment: How?... olive branch

Comment: We already went over this - copy a Logic project, Photo library or anything from a Time Machine drive to FAT & see what happens.

Comment: I understand your point of view.  But that point is mac specific, and has no relevance when applied to a thumb drive is inserted and read from. That is not a destructive operation.  Please read the OP.

Comment: The OP **specifically** mentioned it - "Is it possible that a file …  become inaccessible". **Yes it is**. Hence my initial downvote & comment.